# Do "elision" and "ratatouille" have unmarked plural forms?

Tags: etymology, latin, french, irregular-plurals, software-bugs

[image]

According to *Microsoft® Encarta® 2009*, the word *elision* has an unmarked plural *elision* (no -s suffix) as an alternative to *elisions.*

Can "elision" be used as a plural form? If so, is it due to its Latin origin?

A similar example I've found is *ratatouille*, but I am ignorant of [the pronunciation of its plural in French](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ratatouilles#French).

[image]

Comment: Please type your images' relevant text below the images (or, even better, instead of them) in *plain text*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129522/discussion-on-question-by-gjc-do-elision-and-ratatouille-have-unmarked-plura).

Answer (score 15):

I can't imagine why Encarta would say that. Merriam-Webster, American Heritage, and the OED fail to mention an alternative plural without the -s. (The same is true for *ratatouille*. If you want to see for yourself what unusual plurals are indicated, search any of those dictionaries for "octopus" or "deer".)

There is nothing of the Latin that would indicate "elision" can be plural. The Latin word *elisio* is your run-of-the-mill third declension noun. The plural (nominative and accusative) in Latin is [*elisiones*](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/fulgentius/fulgentius2.shtml), which in English is virtually always a simple -s. Cf. L. *machinationes* with E. "machinations."

My guess is that Encarta is simply wrong or that there might be some specialized, non-standard usage that somehow adopted a singular word for its plural, but I wouldn't trust Encarta to relay that without attestation. You're safer going with the three other dictionaries instead.

Comment: That's right. Microsoft is again spouting arrant nonsense. Both *these ❌elision are* and *these ❌ratatouille are* are thoroughly ungrammatical.

Answer (score 4):

*Ratatouille*, at least in French, has both a singular form (*ratatouille*) and a plural one (*ratatouilles*, and only this one).

The plural form is not used much, but makes sense in some context (e.g. *toutes les ratatouilles ne se ressemblent pas* - *ratatouilles are not made equal*)

Comment: Then again, "the _ contest" will appear unmarked for any English noun (the apple contest, the pie contest, etc.) even though those words have only marked plurals. Something to do with forming the compound noun "_ contest" using the singular form every time, I would imagine.

Comment: @user45266 They're not syntactically plural when they're in that position, though.

Comment: @user45266: you are right, I chose a bad example. I will update the answer

Answer (score 1):

I googled (in quotes)

```
"many elision"
```

and found nothing other than a typo:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjzo4nWhLvyAhVCK80KHb9IA5AQFnoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fartistryalliance.net%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2019%2F05%2Fconfigurations2.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2xICOW1DOYVnrjBIdWJBQD  "How many elision can you find in The Orill Wheel"

Right on p. 1 the document mentions "elisions" in all caps and in bold. At the bottom, you see "Now find elisions in..." and "How many other elisions..." It's a typo.

Comment: Right on p. 1 the document mentions "elisions" in all caps and in bold. At the bottom, you see "Now find elisions in..." and "How many other elisions..." It's just a typo.

Comment: great work @cmw !